# How do I stop IE6 clipping an element positioned outside its parent via negative margins?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have an element positioned outisde its parent via negative margins, like this:

```
<style>
.parent {
    height: 1%;
}

.element {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
</style>

...

<div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Element</div>
</div>
```

In Internet Explorer 6, the part of `.element` positioned outside of its parent element is clipped, i.e. invisible, hidden, cut off. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign `position: relative;` to `.element`, like this:

```
<style>
.parent {
    height: 1%;
}

.element {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -4px;
    position: relative; /* Fixes clipping issue in IE 6 */
}
</style>

...

<div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Element</div>
</div>
```

This is only necessary if the parent element hasLayout (which is too big a can of worms to get into here).

Comment: Awesome i've been struggling with this issue for days!!! finally got a fix that works :)

Comment: Interesting. I've had this problem several times before and indeed spent hours trying various changes in the CSS to no avail. This seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.parent {
    height: 1%;
    overflow: auto;
    _zoom: 1; /*ie6 hack forces has layout*/
}

.element {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: That doesn’t seem to fix the issue. I think `height: 1%` should force hasLayout on `.parent` anyway; you shouldn’t need `zoom: 1` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with negative margins combined with floats in IE6.

If you can, get rid of the float:

```
.element {
   float: none:
   zoom: 1;
}
```